# Does Spring Data come with hibernate embedded?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, maven, spring-data

a little background here.I've been working with spring+hibernate(JPA+Session)+maven for while now.I'm used to Hibernate GenericDAO for all the basic CRUD functionality. Most of the time i use this technology stack i have to get their dependency one by one. Now trying to move towards this newly created Spring Data, and trying to figure out how to leverage on it.

So i've read couple of tutorial already and it seems cool but it seems i've not seen anybody get the `hibernate dependendy`, nor the `cglib` nor `asm` especially when using [spring-data-jpa](http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2011/08/01/simpler-jpa-with-spring-data-jpa/).

Can anyone enlighten me? thanks for reading this

Comment: "to get their dependency one by one" can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data JPA is built on top of JPA with some quirks to work around inadequatenesses of the implementations. We have optional dependencies towards Hibernate, EclipseLink and OpenJPA and run our test cases against those three. Nevertheless all these dependencies are marked as `optional` so it's up to the user to configure a persistence provider of choice for runtime.

Comment: Nice to meet you Oliver. downloaded your presentation but have not watched it yet

Comment: So i got the fact One can choose a persistence provider but i wanted to find out those dependencies of the spring-data-jpa  in the link i provided, we do not need to add them anymore like previously is that correct?but where do you choose the actual persitence provider? say i want to use OpenJPA?

Comment: Just have a look at the `pom.xml` of Spring Data JPA. There's a section `Persistence providers` that declare the provider dependencies. Just copy the relevant snippet into your pom and remove the `<optional>true</optional` elements.

Comment: i see thanks then, pretty neat work!! no more hustling to find out which version of artifact works with which other version embedded in another artifact.